# Identical MIME type Strings wont return true on a comparison operation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I can't seem to make a ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds MIMETYPE constant match with the one I queried for in a  cursor. I've tested the two string and they look identical but the don't return "true" when I compare them in a condition.

Here's a code snippet of the method this problem occurs in:

```
    //gets all the information from the cursor and puts into its respective ArrayList
    for(int i=0; i<C.getCount(); i++){
        HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<String,String>();
        info.put(C.getString(3),C.getString(4));
        Log.d(TAG, "Itertation: "+i);
        Log.d(TAG, "Row Data MIMETYPE: "+C.getString(2));
        Log.d(TAG, "Phone MIMETYPE constant: "+ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE); //this line and the above line return the exact same string when the data types match
        if(C.getString(2) == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE){
            Log.d(TAG, "I have entered the phone condition");//does not enter even if they are identical
            phoneNum.add(info);
        }else if(C.getString(2) == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE){
            Log.d(TAG, "I have entered the Email condition");//does not enter
            emailAddress.add(info);
        }else if(C.getString(2) == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE){
            Log.d(TAG, "I have entered the Address condition");//does not enter
            postalAddress.add(info);
        }
        C.moveToNext();
    }
```

C.getString(2) is the MIMETYPe of that row. 
Here's a snippet of the query and its parameters

```
//query properties
private Uri mUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
private String[] mProjections = {ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, 
        ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, ContactsContract.Data.DATA2};
private String mSelection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+ "='"; //the ending of this gets added in the code
private String[] mArgs = null;
private String mSortOrder = null;

C = getContentResolver().query(mUri, mProjections, mSelection , mArgs, mSortOrder);
```

I have no clue the comparison doesn't return true. When I check LogChat for the iteration that should match I get this:

```
07-13 17:11:48.764: D/ContactDetail(2904): Itertation: 0
07-13 17:11:48.764: D/ContactDetail(2904): Row Data MIMETYPE: vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2
07-13 17:11:48.764: D/ContactDetail(2904): Phone MIMETYPE constant: vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working? From my understanding even though I get the constant MIMETYPE from CommonDataKinds and not Data(can't seem to find a constant there. Let me know if there is a constant in Data) it should be the same as the MIMETYPE from my query, but maybe they are actually different. Other than that I have no idea why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare Strings.

Comment: Using `==` on Java objects compares the identity (same object). You need equality, therefore call `equals()` method instead